# C++ Formatter to Un-split lines

Tags: c++, formatting, code-formatting

Is there a program (like Astyle) which can UN-split lines?

Example:

```
// These
void foo(
         int one,
         int two,
         double three);
double a = b *
           c;

// Becomes this
void foo(int one, int two, double three);
double a = b * c;
```

Comment: Have you look at clang-format, uncrustify ?

Comment: Decent IDE could also do this, for example Eclipse has format option.

Comment: @Jarod42 Just took a look at the clang-format docs and didn't see anything. Uncrustify looks like it will be hard to figure out...

Comment: I use Codelite which has an integration of AStyle/clang-format, and it does what you want (with clang-format). Too lazy to search the corresponding option for command line.

Comment: @Jarod42 If you did you could write an answer for me to accept ;)

Comment: Not fully automated, but the `J` action in Vim is helpful when you want to do this a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any decent IDE with regex search replace capabilities you can match this: `,\s*\r\n\s*(.*)`
And replace with this: `, $1`

This assumes `\r\n` is your newline match and `$1` is how you print your first capture.

**EDIT:**

This is an easy change to your match code if you want to add in some other symbols: `[,+*-]\s*\r\n\s*(.*)`

One thing you'll have to look out for is commented lines like this:

```
// blah,
// blah*
// blah
```

Because the regex will pick them up as well.

Comment: Thanks! Not really fair, but I changed the example a little bit to show other things I am running into.

Comment: @chewsocks No problem. That's a simple regex change. I edited the answer.